# Strange behavior of the except-function of a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to utilize the Except-Function of a SortedDicationary but I'm running crazy as it does not behave as I would have expected. The Excpet function works as long as the entries of the dictionary are of a simple data type. However, I'd like to store objects in the dictionay.

Here is my sample:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace DictionaryTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SortedDictionary<string, Object> objects = new SortedDictionary<string, Object>();
            SortedDictionary<string, Object> objects2 = new SortedDictionary<string, Object>();




            objects.Add("A", new Object());
            objects.Add("B", new Object());
            objects2.Add("A", new Object());

            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Object>> objects_a_only = objects.Except(objects2);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> o in objects_a_only)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o.Key);


            }
            Console.WriteLine("Program finished. Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to only get 'A' as output but it actually returns 'A' and 'B'.

As far as I understood it matching only takes place based on the Key of each entry. So I do not see any reason to work with a customized compare-class.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

`Except` is not a method on `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.
It is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.
In the case of a sorted dictionary, `T` is actually `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

So, `Except` compares instances of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.
Two instances of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` are considered the same if the `Key` and the `Value` are the same.
Because you create a new `object` instance every time, all three instances of the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` are considered not equal to each other.
You can easily verify this by changing your code to this:

```
var o = new object();
objects.Add("A", o);
objects.Add("B", new Object());
objects2.Add("A", o);
```

The result of `objects.Except(objects2)` will now be only the entry with the key `"B"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) it uses the default equality comparer, which for the `KeyValuePair` type compares both the keys and the values. You could use this approach instead:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Object>> objects_a_only = objects
        .Where(kvp => !objects2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key));
```

Comment: @Norbert: I assume that you just haven't noticed that you were using an extension method of `Enumerable` which is made for every kind of collection and sometimes works different as someone would expect. The same would happen if you'd use `Except` on a `List<CustomClass>` until you'd implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.